Getting HTTP status=404 error while creating an orchestration pipeline on Matllion
I am new to Matillion while creating an orchestration pipeline i am getting a validation error Environment connection creation failed: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: HTTP status=404.
I am using a Database Query component and the database Type is a Snowflake. I entered the correct connection_url but still getting the error


What authentication type do you have on your Snowflake source? Is MFA enforced, or is it federated? Can you connect to the source using the SnowSQL CLI client?
